# replacing contents of a container in Jquery

Tags: jquery, settimeout, chatbot

Close to finishing my Chatbot now and one of the last few touches is to add a place holder for when the bot is typing. i want to delay the response for an amount of time that is dependent on the length of the response. During the delay i want a placeholder to appear in the html.

the function begins

```
function send_message(message){

var prevState = $('#container').html();


$("#container").html(prevState + "<span class = 'currentMessage'>" + "<span class = 'placeholderBot'>Donny is typing... </span>" + "</span>");
```

then be replaced by

```
$("#container").html(prevState + "<span class = 'currentMessage'>" + "<span class = 'bot'>Donny: </span>" + message + "</span>");
```

is there a way to perform the first move, pause, then reverse that action and perform the second?

I've had a partial success with a set timeout function but there are still bugs

I'm adding a codepen for those of a mind

https://codepen.io/BenjieCrumpet/pen/OxNdGa

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you append the `message` in the second `span`... But that would be the "time" to target the `.placeholderBot`.

I suppose you do something like :

```
$(".currentMessage").append(message);
```

Then you can try to use of [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/):

```
$(".currentMessage .placeholderBot").replaceWith("<span class = 'bot'>Donny: </span>");
```

`.replaceWith()` squarely replaces the matching element (not only its content) with what's provided as argument.

---

**EDIT**

My answer was about to use the elements you have in your first appending:

```
$("#container").html(prevState + "<span class = 'currentMessage'>" + "<span class = 'placeholderBot'>Donny is typing... </span>" + "</span>");
```

`.currentMessage` and `.placeholderBot` can be used to inject the "bot is typing" and the message you get from server.

I made you an usage demo.

```js
function bot(){
  var prevState = $("#container").html()+"Guest: "+$("#guestInput").val()+"<br>";

  $("#container").html(prevState + "<span class='currentMessage'>" + "<span class='placeholderBot'>Donny is typing... </span>" + "</span><br>");

  // Simulating a delay here.
  setTimeout(function(){
    var message= "A random answer.";

    $(".currentMessage").append(message);
    $(".currentMessage .placeholderBot").replaceWith("<span class='bot'>Donny: </span>");

    $(".currentMessage").toggleClass("currentMessage oldMessage");
    $("#guestInput").val("");
  },2000);
}

$("#guestInput").on("change",function(e){
  bot();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  ---SYSTEM---: Welcome to chatbot.<br>
  <br>
  
</div>
<br>
<input type="text" id="guestInput">
```

Notice `$(".currentMessage").toggleClass("currentMessage oldMessage");`
That is to remove the class `currentMessage` from the last bot answer and replace it by another class. If not, the next message may be injected at the wrong place.

That is the same as:
`$(".currentMessage").removeClass("currentMessage").addClass("oldMessage");`

Comment: $("#container").html(prevState + typing);
       $("#container").html(prevState + actual);

Comment: I edited... My answer was correct. But it looks like you need to see it working.

Comment: thaks for your help, still trying to get it working on my bot. Can you help to uinderstand where the "oldMessage" comes from?

Comment: I fixed the delay quick [here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ZXpxWE?editors=0111)... Have a look.